# Slow transfer rate of large TCP packets

Tags: c#, c++, .net, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to dump data over TCP sockets from an embedded device running a Blackfin533 processor and plot it on a Win Forms progam running on my computer.

The following C++ code is running on the embedded device and works as expected:

```
while(1)
{   
    UpdateDataArray();          
    int sent = send(m_Socket, (UINT8 *)dataArray, 10000, 0);
    if(sent <= 0)
        break;
}
```

My client side program is constantly receiving and plotting the data. The data gets received and the plot updated every ~7ms. So far so good.

Now if instead of just dumping the data, I would like the client to have to request a new array to be sent by sending the string "Next" every iteration:

```
while(1)
{   
    int recvLen = recv(m_Socket, (char *)dataInArray, 513, 0);
    if(recvLen <= 0)
        break;

    if(!ReceivedCommand("Next"))
        break;

    UpdateDataArray();          
    int sentLen = send(m_Socket, (char *)dataOutArray, 10000, 0);
    if(sentLen <= 0)
        break;
}
```

Now all of a sudden the refresh rate is around 210ms! I suspected that this might have something to do with the MTU size being 1500bytes, and sure enough, if I just send 1400bytes instead of 10000, the refresh rate drops to 1ms. At 1500bytes it goes up to 210ms again.

Why is the data being transferred at 7ms in the first scenario, but takes 30x times as long in the second?

**Edit:** After running wireshark it became clear that the delay is on the *receiving* machine, not on the embedded device.

Server sending 1400 byte package:

[image: Server sending 1400 byte package]

Server sending 1500 byte package:

[image]

This is how the client is receiving the data:

```
while(1)
{
    refreshRateStopWatch.Start();

    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Next");

    int bytesSent1 = senderSock.Send(msg);
    if (bytesSent1 == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    int bytesRec1 = senderSock.Receive(bytes);
    if (bytesRec1 == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

   refreshRateStopWatch.Stop();
   refreshRate = refreshRateStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
   refreshRateStopWatch.Reset();

    Plot(bytes);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are waiting for "Next" to come through and using TCP will block it until 3 trips have been made (Send/Response/Ack). If you're trying to stream stuff then UDP might be a better aproach

Comment: @Neijwiert But then why is it so fast when i only send 1400 bytes back, even when I'm waiting for the "Next"?

Comment: So what happens when you debug it?  Are you receiving data but it happens to not be "Next" perfectly?

Comment: Well you're kind of leaving us in the dark by not posting the definition of `ReceivedCommand` and `UpdataDataArray`

Comment: @UKMonkey The data is being received correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is the delay on the other side of the socket?

Comment: Run wireshark on the receiving machine and take a look. You'll be able to see all the packet headers and the relative timings.

Comment: @Neijwiert I purposely left them out as I don't think they matter. I see the same pattern when I remove all code except 'send' and 'recv'

Comment: Pipelining appears to be likely. Below the packet size, `recv()` immediately returns, and the OS sends the packet out at the first available opportunity. Above the threshold, `recv()` waits until most of the submitted buffer has been sent, and the remainder, if any, is left in the internal socket buffer to be pushed out, once again, at the first available opportunity.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So would you say that the solution is manually split up data so that it is always below packet size and then reassemble it on the receiving machine?

Comment: @Useless That was a good tip.. See edit. Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't this due to TCP buffering? Set `TCP_NODELAY` to force packet sending as soon as possible.

Comment: [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) maybe?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thank you so much! Setting TCP_NODELAY solved the problem!

Comment: @Eljay Thanks so much! Like I said to Jean-Baptiste, setting TCP_NODELAY solved it.